# Apply as.POSIXct function into multiple columns

Tags: r

I want to convert multiple column containing date and timestamp as POSIXct. How to convert multiple columns with as.POSIXct function?

| tgl1p | tgl2bc |
| --- | --- |
| 2021-12-10 09:54:00 | 2022-01-05 08:29:36 |
| 2021-05-19 15:37:43 | 2021-05-21 11:05:45 |
| 2021-12-13 16:44:01 | 2021-12-17 08:51:31 |

Answer (score 3):

```r
library(tidyverse)

data <- tibble(tgl1 = "2021-12-10 10:00:32", tgl2 = "2021-12-13 14:59:14")

data %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("tgl"), as.POSIXct))
#> # A tibble: 1 × 2
#>   tgl1                tgl2               
#>   <dttm>              <dttm>             
#> 1 2021-12-10 10:00:32 2021-12-13 14:59:14
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>